# How to manage IAM User Secret Keys in Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I have a Django project (deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk) that uses several AWS services (SES, S3, etc.) through an IAM user. I am wondering what the best way to **store this IAM user's credentials** in the Django project is.

I have thought of a few approaches and have a few questions for each:

1. Make a `.env` file with the credentials. *Can this be hacked though? Is this the most secure way?*
2. Use `Amazon Secrets Manager` to create a secret with the credentials. *I tried this, but then realized that you need to supply credentials to use it ().*

Is there a better method? **What would you recommend?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use IAM user credentials on AWS compute services (EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, Lambda, etc.)

Instead, use an IAM role. See [Managing Elastic Beanstalk instance profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html).

Per [What is the difference between an IAM role and an IAM user?](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#:%7E:text=An%20IAM%20user%20has%20permanent,AWS%20service%20such%20as%20EC2.)

> An IAM user has permanent long-term credentials and is used to
> directly interact with AWS services. IAM roles
> are meant to be assumed by authorized entities, such as
> applications ...

Comment: I see, this makes sense. How does it work to give the credentials to Django though?

Comment: It depends how you are accessing AWS services (SES, S3). If you're using the native AWS SDK for Python (boto3) then you don't need to explicitly give it credentials as it can retrieve them automatically from the instance profile. If you're using a custom Django extension to access AWS services, then you'll have to read its documentation for how to supply credentials.

Comment: Ok, will do this. (btw, me and NGI are working together, hence why you see us both here ;0)